# How to get INT-type id from Table A and insert it into another table? In PHP

Tags: php, mysql

**I am not doing insert query, so the mysqli_insert_id doesnt' work.**

I need to **select** an id(Primary, INT) from Table A which will be inserted into Table B.

My Tables Structure:

```
Table book:
-id (Primary, Auto Increment, INT)
-title
-publisher_id (Foreign key to Table publisher.pub_id, INT)

Table publisher:
-pub_id (Primary, Auto Increment, INT)
-publisher
```

I tried like this:

```
$query ="SELECT pub_id FROM book WHERE publisher = '$publisher' ";
$result=$mysqli->query($query);
$pub_id=$result->fetch_assoc();

$query ="INSERT INTO book (title,publisher_id)
              VALUES ('$title', '$pub_id['pub_id']')";
$mysqli->query($query);
```

Then I got error message like:

```
syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)
```

Is there something wrong with the data type or something else?

How to get INT-type id from Table book and insert it into another table?

Comment: What line the error says?

Comment: This line     $query ="INSERT INTO book (title,publisher_id)
              VALUES ('$title', '$pub_id['pub_id']')";

Comment: When you say `SELECT pub_id FROM book`, you mean `FROM publisher` right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are doing this:

```
$query ="INSERT INTO book (title,publisher_id)
              VALUES ('$title', '$pub_id['pub_id']')";
```

Try this instead:

```
$query ="INSERT INTO book (title,publisher_id)
              VALUES ('$title', '".$pub_id['pub_id']."')";
```

Comment: Glad it helped, if this answer solves your problem you can mark it as solved, also you may want to escape the `$title` variable if it's not escaped before.

Comment: Thanks, btw, why  ' ".$pub_id['pub_id']." ' works while '$pub_id['pub_id']' doesn't ?

Comment: when I use ' ".$pub_id['pub_id']." '  in a UPDATE query, like this: SET pub_id =' ".$pub_id['pub_id']." '  Then i got a error message" undefined variable"